# java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.proxy2.$Proxy15 cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium

This is my util class:

```
public class AndriodActions {

    AndroidDriver driver;

    public AndriodActions(AndroidDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver;

    }

    public void longPressAction(WebElement element) {

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: longClickGesture",
                ImmutableMap.of("elementId", ((RemoteWebElement) element), "duration", 5000));

    }
}
```

//***************************************************************************************************//

This is pom page:

```
public class LoginPageLocators extends AndriodActions {

    AndroidDriver driver;

    public LoginPageLocators(AndroidDriver driver) {

        super(driver);
        this.driver = driver;

        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

    }

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.view.View[@index='1']")
    private WebElement AppVersion;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@index='2']")
    private WebElement IPAdress;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='Save']")
    private WebElement SaveButton;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@text='Email']")
    private WebElement EmailAddress;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@text='Password']")
    private WebElement Password;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='SUBMIT']")
    private WebElement SubmitButton;

    public void setIpAddress(String address) {

        longPressAction(AppVersion);
        IPAdress.clear();
        IPAdress.sendKeys(address);
        SaveButton.click();

    }
```

//*******************************************************************************************************//
This is my execution class:

```
public class TestExecution extends BaseClass {

    @Test
    public void IpAddressSetup() throws Exception {

        String ipaddress = "https://facebook.com";

        LoginPageLocators htmlElementLocators = new LoginPageLocators(driver);
        htmlElementLocators.setIpAddress(ipaddress);

    }
```

//***************************************************************************************************//

This is im getting in console:

```
FAILED: IpAddressSetup
java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.proxy2.$Proxy15 cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement (jdk.proxy2.$Proxy15 is in module jdk.proxy2 of loader 'app'; org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.Utils.AndriodActions.longPressAction(AndriodActions.java:25)
    at com.Locators.LoginPageLocators.setIpAddress(LoginPageLocators.java:46)
    at com.testcases.TestExecution.IpAddressSetup(TestExecution.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I'm trying to press too hard on the server text. However, it generates an error.

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40095188/2070127)